# Converting data from geodatabase to latitude and longitude format

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, land-cover, land-classification

I am computer science student with no experience in Geographic information systems. I am trying to convert a geodatabse [National land cover database](http://www.mrlc.gov/nlcdalbedo_data.php) to a latitude and longitude format. This database only has layer for some reason and no tables. So, far from my research I came to know about few tools such as ArcGIS etc to convert the data.

Can someone suggest me some procedure to convert this data to latitude and longitude format?

If someone knows of some better database, can they redirect me towards it.

Comment: If you just want fields for latitude and longitude, you can use [Add XY Locations](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-xy-coordinates.htm) with an output coordinate system in the projection of your choice. You'll want a geographic coordinate system (GCS) to get lat/long instead of Cartesian XY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert a geodatabase to lat long. If i have understood correctly, your feature class type in the geodatabase is polygon, the solution is same for other feature class type (point and polyline).

1. import feature class to the arcmap
2. use [feature vertices to point](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) tool and convert the vertices(
   the main spatial component of featrures) to point.
3. use  [Add XY Coordinates](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-xy-coordinates.htm)  to calculate the lat and long for each point.

If your feature class type is Point, just use Add XY Coordinates.You can [read geometry](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/reading-geometries.htm) using python and arcpy in ArcGIS as well

Comment: Right click to the feature class and click open attribute table.click on the icon in left top of the table .select export.

Answer (score 1):

You may have access to a student license for ArcGIS.  However, for a simple task such as this, it will be easier to download and install QGIS.  QGIS is a free, open source GIS platform.

QGIS:  http://www.qgis.org/en/site/

Once you install QGIS, add a vector layer, select 'directory' and type 'OpenFileGDB'.  You will then be able to access all the layers in the geodatabase.  Select the layers you want to add to the map.

Then use the coordinate tools to calculate the latitude and longitude.

If you're trying to convert the data into a lat long projection system, use the projection tool to project the data into WGS84 or other geographic coordinate system.

It's not clear if you just want to get the coordinates in lat long or if you are trying to reproject your data to a different projection.  I think you are just chasing coordinates.

There is a lot of documentation available for calculating coordinates in QGIS on this site and elsewhere online.  If you get stuck after installing QGIS, check out the QGIS documentation: http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/index.html

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how to project data from the input format gdb file to the WGS84 format? I am new to this software.

Comment: By that I mean converting the data in to lat/long system.

Comment: @ShreyJoshi Vector>Data Management Tools>Reproject Layer...  Select the layer you want to reproject.  Select WGS84 as the target crs.  Click the ... under Reprojected to save the layer to a file.  Click Run.